# Django {% crispy %} tag vs {{ form|crispy }} filter what's the difference?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to wrap my head around what crispy forms is doing in the background.

When I put the tag `{% crispy form %}` into my HTML block, my form layouts and crispy bootstrap formatting (`from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Row, Column` and `from crispy_forms.bootstrap import AppendedText, InlineRadios` ) is rendered properly but the **submit button does not post** to my model or redirect the user.

When I put the tag `{{ form|crispy }}` into my HTML block, my form **layout is not rendered** but the submit button does work and posts the user input to my model.

I'm trying to figure out how to get both a nice layout *and* have a functional HTML form.

Comment: The [documentation](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html) explains it. If you use the `crispy` **filter**, it's like Django's `as_p` method: you need to wrap the form in the `<form>` tag yourself and the helper isn't used. If you use the `crispy` **tag**, the <form> wrapper is added, but you should define a helper which also defines the action (where you want to submit the form). Look at your HTML source in your browser to see the output and check why the submit button doesn't submit the form (is `action` correct? is `method` correct?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured it out,

You have to add the POST button to your helper in Python in the model/form for the `{% crispy form %}` tag to work.

I originally had a submit button in HTML `<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>` which only worked with the crispy filter `{{ form|crispy }}`

```py
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.layout = Layout(AppendedText('foo','bar')
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-primary'))
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
```

Answer (score -1):

For me it also worked to have the submit button outside of the form:

```
<div class="accounts-form">
<form id="signupform" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy form %}
    {% if redirect_field_value %}
        <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}"/>
    {% endif %}
</form>
<button class="btn-accounts" form="signupform" type="submit">Account erstellen</button>
```